# Highlighting text and then tapping delete only deletes 1 character

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

If I highlight text (drag and select with mouse) then hit delete, it sometimes only deletes 1 character, from the selection. Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: It would help us if you provided some more info, such as what you're using, OS, specific apps, etc.  You can see [ask] on how to ask questions that have a good chance at getting answers.

Comment: El Capitan and Facebook.com in Chrome

Comment: Is this only happening in Facebook in Chrome? Or across your entire system?

Comment: I'm going to have to watch closer. I can't replicate it in Skype, right now, at least.

Comment: @User so the problem is still happening in Chrome? Or is it just on Facebook? It would be helpful if you added more context/information to your question.